# Why does KS test return p=0 for my data?

Tags: inference, computational-statistics

I am comparing two sets of data which clearly have the same distribution. Y is is the experimentally observed data, while y_pred is the gaussian fit to Y.

Clearly this is a good fit, so I expect them to have the same statistical distribution.

[image: Comparison of 2 sets of data]

However, when I run the following code:

```
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

ks_2samp(y_pred, y)
```

I get the following result:

```
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.9239583333333333, pvalue=0.0)
```

Since p is 0, I reject the null hypothesis and the two sets of data have *different* distributions.

How do I make sense of this?

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: You are right, @GermanDemidov. Before I go ahead and post the data, you may be able to answer this from just this info. In the y data, the tails remain at 7 the entire time, while of course the gaussian fit goes to 0 very quickly. What is the right way to go about this? Clearly the peak has the same distribution, and I am trying to quantify this. Should my fit y_pred instead be fitted as a constant + gaussian instead of just gaussian?

Comment: Sorry removed my comment since I was doubting my conclusions. It was about the heavy tails. Good that I was helpful.

Comment: @TimofeyAbramski you can model it as a mixture of a uniform and normal distribution, however the plot in general is confusing - these are not densities of distributions (area under the curve will not integrate into 1), but something like "histograms", if I get it correctly...

Comment: @GermanDemidov This data is actually modelling a voltage response versus an input voltage (although I have just plotted versus data index), so my understanding would be that a histogram wouldn't be right here. I'm trying to quantify that a voltage spike for a particular input voltage happens to be gaussian.

Comment: @TimofeyAbramski then I would substract 7 from all the data points (you may infer it as a mixture component using mixture modelling, but why overcomplicate things) and, hm, sample values from the remaining curve. Sampling probability should be equal to the "height" of the plot. And then you may apply KS test. The amount of data points inside the "bell" of the normal curve is too low now! like, 97% of the points should be inside the bell!

Comment: Thanks @GermanDemidov. All of those tail points actually deviate by roughly 7, so if I take away 7 there will still be some small deviations from 0, like [0.3,-0.3], will this still cause the same issue when fitting? And sorry but what do you mean sample values from the curve? Are you talking about somehow normalising my curve so that the integral is 1?

Comment: @TimofeyAbramski in general I think you are trying to compare incomparable things. Normal density (or histogram) can not be below 0. There is something fundamentally wrong with this approach, but I am not a statistical boss, so I can not explain it plainly =) roughly speaking, you try to fit a function to data points - which is fine - but I can not grasp the reasoning why this function should be a "distribution function" and why do you need to test it with statistical methods

Comment: rejecting the null hypothesis doesn't prove that the data come from 2 different distributions. It just indicates that if the distributions were the same it would be unlikely to see two data sets this different. The p-value of 0 is confusing. It seems that wouldn't happen unless the distributions were discrete. Also keep in mind that the larger the data sets are the greater is the chance to detect small differences between 2 distributions.

Comment: I had physics classes long time ago, but - in my opinion from my understanding of your problem - you should approach the modelling from the different perspective, like, something https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_response or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response . If it looks like a normal distribution - it does not mean that it is good to model it with normal distribution.

Comment: Per [@MichaelChernick's comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435562/why-does-ks-test-return-p-0-for-my-data#comment811930_435562), this may just be a case of "if you have an enormous sample size, then even tiny deviations between the distributions will be statistically (!) significant". How many data points do you have? If your plot is a histogram-like thing, then I'm guessing at the order of 10,000, which is a size at which this effect definitely comes into play.

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica I had an impression that x-axis here represents time (the dots look uniformly distributed for me and start at 0), and y-axis is the measurement and in general it is not a sample from a distribution, it is just a bell shaped function which represent some stochastic process.